# How to properly connect linter in Atom with jshint

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, jshint, lint

I want to use the linter package in the Atom Editor. I have installed the packages "linter" and "linter-jshint". Additionally I installed jshint via npm (globally) and downloaded the jshint-repo from GitHub.

When I just try to run the linter on an open .js file in Atom, it fails with message "Error running JSHint". The same happens if I point the executablePath for linter-jshint in the Atom config to the downloaded repo folder.

When I set the executablePath to the node.js Module ("linter-jshint": executablePath: "C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jshint") it just shows a warning ("JSHint return an invalid response, check your console for more info"). Developer Tools console shows:

> [Linter-JSHint] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object. (main.js:157)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (C:\Users\Username.atom\packages\linter-jshint\lib\main.js:3)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103)

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to point to another subdir or a specific file?

Username contains space and a german umlaut "ö".

PS: I can execute jshint from command line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

On *Executable Path* field, you should actually point to jshint executable file, like this:

```
H:\node_modules\jshint\bin\jshint
```